# Login to Gmail Web Interface using OAuth

Tags: android, oauth, gmail

I need to access the Gmail web interface from within a `WebView` in my Activity. For obvious security/trust reasons, I'd like to avoid asking the user for his Gmail credentials and storing them somewhere, but rather use something like OAuth to be granted access to Gmail. From what I've found, OAuth is only implemented for IMAP and SMTP-access to the Gmail-Account, correct?

Would using `webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);` and letting the user sign in the first time he/she uses the app work? How would I automatically submit the saved details on subsequent app-launches?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to regard your `WebView` as a browser. How does a browser like Chrome let you be automatically signed in each time you visit Gmail? It stores the session cookies from Gmail.

To store cookies from your `WebView` and reuse them the next time, check out [`CookieManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This would "bind" me to the cookie-expiration set by Gmail, meaning that the user would need to sign in again after e.g. 1 week, right? (I don't know the actual expiration time of Gmail's session cookies) I would rather have a solution that is "set-once-and-forget" for the user.

Comment: Well as you already saw, OAuth is only available for IMAP/SMTP and not for loggin in to their Web Frontend. As you don't want to store the user credentials, unfortunately the only way is storing the session cookies.

Comment: If you would store the user credentials, you could try faking the login request that is sent to https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth for automatically logging in a user.