# Automatically login to Gmail using a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, gmail, android-webview

I'd like to use the user's Gmail username and password to automatically login to Gmail inside a `WebView`. Is there any existing code how to do this, as I'm having trouble with it (which hidden fields need to be posted, getting/re-injecting the cookie).

I have tried to simply fill in the username/password-fields using JavaScript, which works, but on submitting the login-form (using JavaScript again), the `WebView` asks the users whether he/she wants the password to be saved, which I need to avoid (to make it truly automatic).

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Can u tell how u have fill the username and password fields using javascript.

Comment: Once the login-form has finished loading in the WebView, you simply use `WebView.loadUrl("javascript: ...;");` to perform javascript-actions on the loaded content. For example:      `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:yourloginform.username.value=\"" + mUsername + "\";");
     mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:yourloginform.username.value=\"" + mPassword + "\";");
     mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:yourloginform.signIn.click();");`

Comment: here yourloginform means what.can u tell clearly how to do this and javascript code for this. i want to load a gmail login webpage with filled credentials.

Comment: Please [create a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for your issue and link it here.

Comment: i have created the qusetion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562497/automatically-load-a-webpage-with-username-and-password-using-webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
mWebSettings.setSavePassword(false);
mWebSettings.setSaveFormData(false)
```

Try this, not sure if both setSave[...] methods are required though.

But wait: Assuming you really just simply fill the login-form with JavaScript, do you store the password in plain text? If so, you shouldn't do that, not only due to security issues. I assume you're asking the user for his/her password via a Dialog.
Asking for the password seems suspicious to a lot of users.

I suggest learning how to save and restore cookies instead.

Comment: Awesome, that works :)! Thank you! I thought it was the other way around (I had setSavePassword(true) and setSaveFormData(true), which I thought would silently save the form data, but it actually makes more sense "your" way! Regarding the issue of saving the username and password: You're absolutely right, I would rather *not* do that, I had another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335761/) on how to avoid that, but don't know how a save/restore cookie-solution would work :-/...

Comment: (if I *would* store the username/password, I would obviously encrypt it, but it's not a solution I'm aiming for)...