# Android open google play in web view while being logged in

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview in my application where I need to open Google Play. The problem is that when I open this WebView for the first time, it asks me to sign in. It is not very convenient for users. Is there a way to make user signed in using system credentials or get credentials from default browser?

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11353220/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar As I understood from that question, he used javascript to inject login and password and needed to not show "save password" alert. But, I want to use system credentials without passing any credentials to fields using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In your webview settings, try below :

```
webView.setSavePassword(false);
webVIew.setSaveFormData(false);
```

Comment: You have to login for first time after applying these methods. I am not sure exactly, but as per the doc, it will save your form details in cookies. So next time, you may be redirected to your profile.

Answer (score 0):

The WebView as part of the app may have only maximal the same permission provided by the app. This permission may be needed in the manifest: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#USE_CREDENTIALS

Comment: Do I need to add something in code? I added this permission and nothing changed

Comment: It seems any third party app is blocked from accessing the account credentials in order to re-use them for an automated login on the WebView. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCOUNT_MANAGER

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chrome Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) library in your app. If user have loggedin in your app using custom tab, user will share same session with chrome browser also.

**sample code**

```
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
    .addDefaultShareMenuItem()
    .setToolbarColor(this.getResources()
        .getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
    .setShowTitle(true)
    .setCloseButtonIcon(backArrow)
    .build();

// This is optional but recommended
CustomTabsHelper.addKeepAliveExtra(this, customTabsIntent.intent);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to parse html of the opened page. As I know, Chrome Tabs doesn't allow that?

Comment: @RustamIbragimov why you want to parse HTML of page ?

Comment: Because I need to have some information about account